# "select ;" why does this statement exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

The query:

```
select ;
```

is valid in postgresql. It returns a tuple with no attribute.

```
# select ;
--
(1 row)
```

It has clear semantics and the result can be used as a subquery:

```
# select 1 from (select )  as rip;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

In fact, one can create a table with no attributes using it. One can even add tuples to it!!

But my question is, why does it exist?

I see value in a select without a from clause, as psql can be used as a calculator:

```
 # select 3 * 6;
 ?column? 
 ----------
         18
 (1 row)
```

and or be used to call a UDF.

But I can not envision a use for `select ;`

it is useful or is it an oddity of postgresql's parser?

Comment: Do you have a _practical_ problem that an answer to this question will address, or is this only a matter of curiosity? See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- as described in the Help Center, Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions about ["actual problems that you face"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

> Empty SELECT Lists

> The list of output expressions after SELECT can be empty, producing a zero-column result table. This is not valid syntax according to the SQL standard. PostgreSQL allows it to be consistent with allowing zero-column tables. However, an empty list is not allowed when DISTINCT is used.